# PHP Send POST request with cookies

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a POST request to a website with a cookie. As simple as that PHP makes it complicated and I have no clue what to do.

This below doesn't send the cookie as I want it to.

```
    $ch = curl_init("https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array()));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, ".ROBLOSECURITY=" . $cookie);
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r ($resp);
```

I am trying to convert this python code into PHP; (this works)

```
    jar = r.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
    jar.set('.ROBLOSECURITY', cookie, domain='.roblox.com', path='/')
    resp = r.post(url="https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout", cookies=jar)
```

output headers:

```
    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Length: 83
    Content-Type: application/json
    Expires: -1
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Roblox-Machine-Id: RP-WEB350
    P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM 
    PRE"
    Date: Sat, 27 Oct 2018 13:24:09 GMT
```

output body:

```
    {"errors":[{"code":0,"message":"Authorization has been denied for this 
    request."}]}
```

Comment: Have a look how CURLOPT_COOKIE works. Your Cookie string is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I did some updates but it still isn't sending the cookie.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, ".ROBLOSECURITY=" . $cookie);

Comment: Please edit your post if you Change something. Why the leading dot?

Comment: Sorry, did that just right now. The dot is a part of the cookie name; it needs to be there.

Comment: Remove  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER?

Comment: @OpalStudio please give us the output of print_r

Comment: Removed HTTPHEADER and updated post with output information

Comment: Where does $cookie come from?

Comment: from a variable I made before, I don't really want to release it publicly here. (it's a string)